# create a new value in mongo db based on current value

Tags: mongodb

```
{
"a" :"2"
"b" : "3"
}
```

I want to create a new "c" that copied his data from "a"
the new update will looks like the following:

```
{
 "a" : "2"
 "b" : "3"
 "c" : "2"
}
```

I tried with `$addfileds` but it does not work

```js
db.letters.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "c": "$a"  
        }},
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the following one by using `$project`.

```js
db.coll.aggregate([ { $project: { "a": 1, "b": 1, "c": "$a" }}]);
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c6becd138395c0c946c19a2"), "a" : "2", "b" : "3", "c" : "2" }
```

Doc: [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: Please just mark the question as a duplicate, as the question has already been answered (with a very highly upvoted answer giving different options for different MongoDB versions) - I linked to the duplicate in my comment. Note that the answer varies based on version of MongoDB being used.